# Custom h1 for pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can anybody help me find out how to set custom h1 for pages? By default in WordPress page title=H1, but what to do if I want to set h1 that doesn't equal page title and don't want to have 2 h1 tags on the page?

Comment: You can set a [custom meta field](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) for pages. If there is a value, then you can use that for the h1, and if not then it will use the page title.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do that from theme customization > typography

Comment: I have no such option

Comment: every WordPress theme comes with customization option